# Chaging the label position for an input at CakePHP 2.2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.2

CakePHP usually place labels before the input, so doing this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('subject');
```

We obtain this:

```
<div class="input text required">
    <label for="TicketSubject">Subject</label>
    <input name="data[Ticket][subject]" maxlength="255" type="text" id="TicketSubject">
</div>
```

Is there any way to place the label after the input to obtain this?

```
<div class="input text required">
    <input name="data[Ticket][subject]" maxlength="255" type="text" id="TicketSubject">
    <label for="TicketSubject">Subject</label>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: you can do this by css or by placing label `$this->Form->label('Ticket.subject')` at your required location

Comment: I consider it not the perfect solution. That's why i was asking.

Comment: yes right @Steve !! got it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The proper way is using the the 'format' option.

```
$this->Form->input('subject', array(
    'format' => array('before', 'input', 'between', 'label', 'after', 'error')
));
```

Didn't anyone read the [API](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper%3a%3ainput) :)

Comment: Note: You can also pass this solution to the `inputDefaults` when creating a form. This causes it to be applied to all inputs of said form.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('subject', array('label' => false, 'after' => $this->Form->label('Subject:')));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this also  -

```
echo $this->Form->input('subject', array('label' => false, 'after' => '<label for="subject">Subject</label>'));
```

Comment: Its similar to the solution given by Paulo, but without using the formHelper. Thanks anyway.